# strictifying tricategories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Every tricategory is equivalent to a Gray-categories. However any Gray-category is not equivalent to a 3-category. As far as I know, this is similar to the fact that braided monoidal categories are not equivalent to symmetric monoidal categories. However the difference between braided and monoidal categories lies in just one axiom: the fact that $B_{x,y} \star B_{y,x}$ is the identity.

So my question is: could you add such an axiom to tricategories in order to make them 'strictifyable' into 3-categories? And if the answer is yes, what isn't it a part of  the definition of a tricategory?

I think such an axiom may look something like $$\omega_{f,g} \star_2 \omega_{g,f} = 1_{f \star_1g}$$ whenever the left-hand-side term is defined, that is when $f$ and $g$ have the same identity as sources and targets.

Side note: of course one could also add this axiom to Gray categories. However I think it cannot be directly encodded into the Gray tensor product, making the definition a bit awkward.

Comment: In what sense is a symmetric monoidal category like a 3-category?

Comment: I do not mean that a symmetric monoidal category is like a 3-category. Only that a symmetric monoidal category is to a braided  monoidal category what a 3-category is to a gray category. To be more precise, one object, one arrow tricategories are precisely braided monoidal categories (whith braiding induced by the interchange isomorphism), and one object, one arrow 3-categories are precisely strict symmetric monoidal categories.

Comment: I see, I guess you rely on the fact that every symmetric monoidal category can be strictified to a strict symmetric monoidal category. So in a sense the question asks whether there is a 3-categorical analogue of a symmetric monoidal category.

Comment: Yes, it is an other way to see it.

Comment: @Dimitri: a *braided* monoidal category is a (weak) 3-category with one object and one morphism. A symmetric monoidal category is an object like this satisfying an additional constraint, one description of which is that it's deloopable to a (weak) 4-category with one object, one morphism, and one 2-morphism. (This is special to the low category number we're working with: in general being symmetric is a structure on top of being braided, not a property.)

Comment: @Qiaochu Right, that's quite well know. The first question was if there is an (explicit) extra structure on a (weak) 3-category which makes it strictifyable. I have never seen it myself. For the second question your answer is correct of course.

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is: could you add such an axiom to tricategories in order to make them 'strictifyable' into 3-categories? And if the answer is yes, what isn't it a part of the definition of a tricategory?

Because we *want* things that aren't strictifiable. It's known that if a space has strictifiable fundamental $n$-groupoid, then its Whitehead brackets up to $\pi_n$ vanish; in particular, $S^2$ has a nontrivial Whitehead bracket $\pi_2 \times \pi_2 \to \pi_3$, so its fundamental $3$-groupoid is not strictifiable (alternatively, the fundamental groupoid of $\Omega^2 S^2$, as a braided monoidal groupoid, is not equivalent to a symmetric monoidal groupoid), and we *want* fundamental $3$-groupoids for the [homotopy hypothesis](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+hypothesis). See, for example, [Homotopy types of strict 3-groupoids](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9810059) by Simpson.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now understand the need for non-strictifiable n-catgegories, but that still doesn't answer completely to my question: bicategories can be strictified and AFAIK they are used nonetheless. One could think that a notion of strictifiable tricategory would be usefull too, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @skysurf3000: yes, but that's special to bicategories. It's special to $n \le 2$ that there aren't any interesting Whitehead brackets, and in fact strict $2$-groupoids can model all homotopy $2$-types. But that just stops being true for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out explicitly that the converse of what you said about Whitehead products does not hold: having them vanish does not guarantee that an n-groupoid is strictifiable. The simplest example is probably $P_3QS^2$, the $3$-type of $QS^2 = \mathrm{colim}\; \Omega^n S^{n+2}$.